# Asp.Net MVC 5 saving rss feed to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rss, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting rss feed from a another website and in case that website shut down, I don't want to get an error. So in order to avoid from error I am trying to save rss feeds to database and if the rss server shuts down I will be able to get feed from my database.
I also want to keep only 6 feed in database. If new feed comes I want to delete the last feed by `PublishDate`

```
 public static List<Rss.News> GetRssFeed(ApplicationDbContext db)
      {
         try
         {
           XDocument feedXml = XDocument.Load("http://www.gib.gov.tr/
           rss/haberguncel.php");
           var feeds = from feed in feedXml.Descendants("item")
           select new Rss.News
           {
             Title = feed.Element("title").Value,
             Link = feed.Element("link").Value,
             Description = feed.Element("description").Value,
             PublishDate=feed.Element("pubdate").Value
           };

           int counter = 0;
           var itemE = db.News.FirstOrDefault();
           if (itemE != feeds.First())
           {
             foreach (var itemC in feeds)
           {
             if (!db.News.Contains(itemC))
             {
               db.News.Add(itemC);
               db.SaveChanges();
               counter += 1;
             }
             else
             {
               break;
             }
             if (counter == 6) { break; }
             }
             }
             return feeds.ToList();
             }
             catch (Exception)
             {
                // i will get data from database here.
             }
  }
```

I am getting this error when I run this code:

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   '...Models.Rss+News'. Only primitive types or enumeration
>   types are supported in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is resulting from this line:

```
if (!db.News.Contains(itemC))
```

In order to do this type of evaluation at the database level, Entity Framework must be able to convert item being compared (`itemC`) into a constant value, which it cannot do with this type, hence your error. You can try casting `db.News` to a list, first, which would switch the evaluation over to in-memory instead at the the database, i.e.:

```
var news = db.News.ToList();
if (news.Contains(itemC))
```

However, you'll have to evaluate how that might affect your application's performance. Alternatively, you simply query on a particular value that you determine as the "key" for lookup. For example, you might say that `Link` will only ever match if it's the same item, so based on that:

```
if (!db.News.Any(m => m.Link == itemC.Link))
```